# Trying to deploy/build for localhost

Tags: meteor, angular-meteor

Trying to deploy/build for localhost and when running the app I keep getting:

> Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: t

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's most likely because you haven't done properly annotated dependency injection. If your app runs ok in development, then  it's almost certain.

Read more about it here

https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/production

Comment: absolutely right, found a few mistakes that broke the build... Thanks!